# SmartyStreets Integrations with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, smartystreets

I have been searching around, looking for information or tutorials to integrate the SmartyStreets API with an application I wish to deploy to AWS. I have created a service that creates entries of addresses in a DynamoDB table, but geolocation data is missing. What I wish to do is use Lambda, and or the AWS API Gateway to watch for new documents, geocode, and update the documents in DynamoDB. I am not having much luck and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable a *trigger* on your DynamoDB table to push new/updated records to a Lambda function. Your Lambda function could take the DynamoDB record, query the third-party API for geolocation data, and then update the record.

See this walkthrough for creating a trigger on your DynamoDB table: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Walkthrough.html

If you have specific questions about how to create the Lambda function or how to query the third-party API from within Lambda, that is probably best asked as a separate question on this site.

Comment: Just be careful about how you write your Lambda trigger function because it will also be triggered after you update the record with the geo data.  Your function needs to be smart about whether the records needs to be updated or not.

Comment: @garnaat has a good point. I would code the Lambda trigger function to only proceed if the geo data is missing from the record, or perhaps use some extra field in the table as a flag to determine if the geo data needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I will post a follow up question about Lambda and a third party API. I have been searching stackoverflow for 6-7 years for answered and always a little hesitant about posting new questions since the answer usually exists if you dig deep enough! Thanks again